# How to get Multi-level marketing (tree) child count

Tags: mysql, codeigniter

I have creating MLM project using **codeigniter** as a front-end **mysql** as a back-end.

Here i have doubt to get child count.

This is my table flow:

[image]

This is my tree flow:

[image]

> This is my query How to get  Multi-level marketing (tree) child count.

For ex: 
Master User have 14 child users.

I tried this code:

View:

```
$product2_users = $this->login->getProduct2Users($top_id);
```

Model:

```
public function getProduct2Users($top_id)
    {
        $count = 0;
        $this->db->select('id');
        $this->db->from('member');
        $this->db->where('sponsor', $top_id);
        $first_child = $this->db->get();

        foreach($first_child->result_array() as $f_child)
        {
            $f_child_id[] = $f_child['id'];
            if(isset($f_child_id))
            {
                $this->db->select('id');
                $this->db->from('member');
                $this->db->where('sponsor', $f_child_id);
                $second_child = $this->db->get();
            }
        }
        echo'<pre>';print_r($second_child->result_array());exit;
        return $first_child->result_array();
    }
```

Comment: would be better to revise your schema.  this isn't going to work without a lot of code. i would suggest a separate tables/table with an fk to user id to store tree data with columns master parent children grandchildren (off top of my head). then producing the tree would be easier. i'd probably ask on the db stack website for help on the structure.

Comment: @Alex : I just want to collect count of total child's. So can you please guide me how to write `mysql query` for this flow

Comment: how deep can your level be ? how many customers does this table have ? you should probably add  a column with this count to your table - and everytime a new customer gets acquired you should update it - because of performance reasons...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

if you really want a solution you've to do this in a recursive manner

something like the following should work

```
public function getCountChilds($id)
{
    $count = 0;

    $query = $this->db
        ->select('id')
        ->from('member')
        ->where('sponsor', $id)
        ->get();

    if ($query->num_rows() > 0)
    {
        foreach($query->result() AS $objChild)
        {
            $count += $this->getCountChilds($objChild->id);
            ++ $count;
        }
    }
    return $count;
}
```

Comment: a thanks is nice - but did it help you - did it solve your problem ? if so accept my answer pls, i mean you asked a question and you didn't respond in any way to the comments beside the fact of your _thanks_ ;)

Comment: Actually just now am implementing your code Its working. Thank you so much. And if you like my question just upvote it.

Answer (score 2):

Try this if your naming convention is same as your tree structure.

```
/*if finding A's child so write A_% and if A1's child then A1_%  */

$query = $this->db->select('*')->from('member')->where("name LIKE 'A_%'")->get();
$query->num_rows();
```